# Is there a way to analyze powershell scripts wih Sonar?

Tags: powershell, sonarqube

Is there a way Sonar can also analyze my PowerShell scripts? 
Does anyone know a plugin?

I know there are some other Ways like [PSScriptSAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) but we would really like to integrate it in our flow with sonar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SonarQube PowerShell Plugin available as of now.

Comment: Is there any way to pass analyzing results back to Sonar from an external analyzer like PSScriptAnalyzer?

Comment: Best course of action for this would be to write your own plugin which is not that difficult. (and if you choose to make it open source, other users might benefit from it)

Comment: It appears there is one now: https://github.com/gretard/sonar-ps-plugin